Nuxt UModel size
I wanto to let Nuxt Model width as 50% of screen? how to do this?
I tried css and tailwind css , does not work
any idea will be more tha welcome!
    <template>
  <div class="w-1/2">
    <UButton icon="i-heroicons-plus" variant="solid" target="_self" @click="open">
      Show Dependencies
    </UButton>
    <UModal v-model="show">
      <UCard>
        <template #header>
          <div class="flex justify-end">
            <UButton icon="i-heroicons-x-mark-20-solid" variant="ghost" @click="close" />
          </div>
        </template>
        <div>
          <div v-if="error">
            <p>Error: {{ error.message }}</p>
          </div>
          <div v-else-if="!rootNodes.length">
            <p>Loading...</p>
          </div>
          <div v-else>
            <div v-for="(node, index) in rootNodes" :key="index">
              <ScheduleNode :schedule="node" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </UCard>
    </UModal>
  </div>
</template>

tailwind css
<div class="w-1/2">

css way
.custom-modal-width {
  width: 50% !important;
  max-width: 50% !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 50%; /* Optional: vertically center the modal */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* Optional: adjust for the top position */
}


This is how you adjust the width and height
 <UModal v-model="isOpen" :overlay="true" :ui="{ width: 'w-full sm:max-w-3xl', height: 'h-[700px]' }">

